# Suppress empty parameters using param tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, url-parameters

I have written JSP that I used with many actions. It has a link with parameters

**The link:**

```
<s:a namespace="/some" action="view">
  <s:param name="purpose" value="%{purpose}"/>
  <s:param name="type" value="%{type}"/>
  <s:property value="%{name}"/>
</s:a>
```

**The action class:**

```
public class ViewAction extends ActionSupport {

  private Long purpose;
  private Long type;
  private String name;

  public Long getPurpose() {
    return purpose;
  }

  public void setPurpose(Long purpose) {
    this.purpose = purpose;
  }

  public Long getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(Long type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Usually I initialize both parameters, but sometimes one parameter is `null`. So, the link is generated with `href` like

```
/context/some/view?purpose=1&type=
```

but I want to remove `&type=`

I tried an example from [Param Examples](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/param.html#param-Examples).

```
<s:a namespace="/some" action="view">
  <s:param name="purpose" value="%{purpose}"/>
  <s:param name="type" value="%{type}"/>
  <s:property value="%{name}"/>
  <s:param name="suppressEmptyParameters" value="true"/>
</s:a>
```

but it didn't work

I also tried

```
<s:a namespace="/some" action="view">
  <s:param name="purpose" value="%{purpose}"/>
  <s:param name="type" value="%{type}" suppressEmptyParameters="true"/>
  <s:property value="%{name}"/>
</s:a>
```

and I got

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Param.end(Param.java:129)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Well that line `<s:param name="suppressEmptyParameters" value="true"/>` doesn't make sense, and it should be removed from the `<s:param>` docs.

The `<s:param name="type" value="%{type}" suppressEmptyParameters="true"/>` is correct way of suppressing empty parameters and it isn't working with not String-s because of the bug [WW-4275](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4275).

Meanwhile, until the next version is released, you can use `toString()` method to avoid `ClassCastException` exception.

```
<s:param name="type" value="type.toString()" suppressEmptyParameters="true"/>
```

Comment: Of course but it is just a warning you can ignore that. Or write an expression checking for null `type == null ? '' : type.toString()`.