# Getting value in s:param from value stack

Tags: jsp, struts2

I upgraded to struts 2.3.16.3 from 2.3.4.1 in my project and the following tag stopped working.

```
<s:param name="%{#key}" value="%{#keyValue}"/>
```

The `param` is being used inside a `s:url` tag. The name part is getting evaluated but the value is not evaluated and shows up as the text "keyValue" inside the url in page. This tag is in a contact jsp which gets included in other jsps. The `key` and `keyValue` are defined in the parent jsp.

For example, `<s:set var="key" value="'billToId'" />
            <s:set var="keyValue" value="'%{billToId}'"/>`

I tried setting the following constant in struts.xml but it did not resolve the issue.

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.enableOGNLEvalExpression" value="true" />
```

I have put in a workaround for this issue but is there any way to read the value from value stack using this ognl expression.

Comment: Ensure you have `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>` in the **included** JSP too, and ensure the tld file is available

Comment: Do you have a code where you do it? Because it seems a duplicate, but I don't get which one.

Comment: @AndreaLigios the taglib is included in the jsp and I'm assuming the tlds are available as other struts related tags are working fine.

Comment: @RomanC I have included the code where key and keyValue are defined. Let me know if I need to add something else.

Comment: Are you using jsp:include or s:include ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/contact/listContacts.jspf"%> is being used

Comment: @kthananjayan this is a problem you should use s:include.

Comment: Don't use fragments for including not static context. Change you file extension from `.jspf` to `.jsp`.

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks for pointing this out. I will change the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remembered a time since `param` tag became accepting values of type `String` only. It could be a bug, but actual parameter values type should be converted to `String` type. See also [Suppress empty parameters using param tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796090/suppress-empty-parameters-using-param-tag).

Answer (score 0):

> Are you using jsp:include or s:include ?
>
> @AndreaLigios `<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/contact/listContacts.jspf"%>` is being used

`<%@ include`  is the static include *directive*, while you should use the dynamic  `<jsp:include/>` tag, or even better, since you are using Struts2, the `<s:include/>` tag.

Read more on this [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763794/1654265).

Comment: Tried using s:include. Now it looks like its trying to evaluate the expression. But I'm getting something like billToId=%25%7BbillToId%7D for the value. It is getting the key instead of keyValue.

Comment: billToId.value ? What is that object, btw ? Completely unclear, but it seems you did the first correct step.

Comment: It's the key that is being set in the parent jsp. The key is coming back for keyValue as well. <s:set var="key" value="'billToId'" />
            <s:set var="keyValue" value="'%{billToId}'"/>. For some reason, the expression %{billToId} is not getting evaluated.