# Struts 2 Url Params when parameter is null, how do I remove it

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, url-parameters

In my `struts.xml` I have:

```
<result name="Alpha" type="redirectAction">
  <param name="actionName">/page1/page2</param>
  <param name="id">$(id)</param>
</result>
```

And in a JSP I also have:

```
<s:url action="page4/page5"><s:param name="id" value="id" /></s:url>
```

These two code blocks are unrelated, just areas trying to achieve a similar outcome.

This all works ok but my issue is, if there is no id url parameter sent through, we just get "?id=" which looks terrible. How do I have the id removed when there is no value for it?

This is like an object context, sometimes a page will have it, sometimes a page wont have it. This is part of a test app hence the ominous page and param names.

Comment: See answer to this question: [Suppress empty parameters using param tag](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25796090/1700321).

Comment: @AleksandrM now why couldnt I find this one!!! Thank you for this - just testing!

Comment: It happens, don't worry. :)

Comment: BTW the issue WW-4275 mentioned in linked answer is resolved in `2.3.20`.

Comment: If you want to thank him @Phish, you could upvote the linked answer

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks for this, I have used this answer to resolve the issue in the struts XML however when I try to use it for the s:url tag, with or without the .toString() I get Attribute suppressEmptyParameters invalid for tag param according to TLD. Is this an out of date framework issue?

Comment: @AleksandrM dammity damn it. Thank you for general you awesomeness.